# Missing File Output When Script Command Runs as su -c command -m user

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script that needs to check if a lockfile exists that only root can access and then the script runs the actual test script that needs to be run as a different user.

The problem is the test script is supposed to generate xml files and those files do not exist. (aka I can't find them)

Relevant part of the script

```
if (mkdir ${lockdir} ) 2> /dev/null; then
   echo $$ > $pidfile
   trap 'rm -rf "$lockdir"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

   if [ -f "$puppetlock" ]
   then
      su -c "/opt/qa-scripts/start-qa-test.sh > /var/log/qaTests/test-$(date +\"m-%d-%T\".log" -m "qaUser"
```

`lockdir` is what gets created when the test is run to signify that the test process has begun.

`puppetlock` checks if puppet is running by looking for the lock file puppet creates.

`qaUser` does not have the rights to check if `puppetlock` exists.

`start-qa-test.sh` ends up calling java to execute an automated test. My `test-date.log` file displays what console would see if the test was run.

However the test is supposed to produce some xml files in a directory called `target`. Those files are missing.

In case it's relevant `start-qa-test.sh` is trying to run something like this

```
nohup=true

/usr/bin/java -cp .:/folderStuff/$jarFile:/opt/folderResources org.junit.runnt.JUNITCore org.some.other.stuff.Here
```

Running `start-qa-test.sh` produces the xml output in the target folder. But running it through `su -c` it does not.

**Edit**

I figured out the answer to this issue.

I changed the line to

`su - qaUser -c "/opt/qa-scripts/start-qa-test.sh > /var/log/qaTests/test-$(date +\"m-%d-%T\".log"`

That allowed the output to show up at the /home/qaUser

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting the output of `stout` and `stderr` in the line:

```
su -c "/opt/qa-scripts/start-qa-test.sh > /var/log/qaTests/test-$(date +\"m-%d-%T\".log" -m "qaUser" 2>&1
```